# Amazon Rekognition automatic multi labeling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I want to use the custom label service of Amazon Rekognition. I have 120 thousand images, and I want to assign labels to them, but I want to do it automatically using the folder name, that is easy if an image has just one label, but my images can have multiple labels assigned to them. How should I organize my images in folders in order to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

I found out Amazon Rekognition doesn't support what I was intent on, so I created a script that updates the labels using AWS CLI.